# почему не удаляются элементы из таблицы?

Tags: javascript, angular

Только начинаю изучать Ангуляр, поэтому прошу прощения за вопрос.

Из шаблона, который представлен в виде таблицы с пагинацией приходит событие клика по кнопке удаления объект из массива. Сама логика реализована в классе сервиса. Внутри само событие удаления отрабатывает, но в TableComponent изменение состояния не приходит.

*table.component.ts*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    TableService
  ]
})

export class TableComponent implements OnInit{
  displayedColumns: Array<String> = ['id', 'Firstname', 'Lastname', 'Middlename', 'Position', 'Date Of Birth', 'Active', 'operations'];
  dataSource: Array<Programmer> = [];

  constructor(private bottomSheet: MatBottomSheet, private tableService: TableService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
  }

  add() {
    this.bottomSheet.open(PopupComponent);
    // this.tableService.add(programmer);
    this.getData();
  }

  getData(): void {
    this.dataSource = this.tableService.getData();
  }

  remove(id: number): void {
    this.tableService.remove(id);
    this.getData();
  }

  edit(id: number) {
    this.bottomSheet.open(PopupComponent);
  }
}
```

*table.service.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Programmer} from "../interfaces/Programmer";
import {Position} from "../enums/Position";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TableService {
  private programmers: Programmer[] = [
    {
      id: 1,
      firstName: 'Павел',
      lastName: 'Петров',
      middleName: '',
      position: Position.JUNIOR,
      dateOfBirth: '11/01/2001',
      active: true
    },
    {
      id: 12,
      firstName: 'Павел',
      lastName: 'Петров',
      middleName: '',
      position: Position.JUNIOR,
      dateOfBirth: '11/01/2001',
      active: true
    },
    {
      id: 13,
      firstName: 'Павел',
      lastName: 'Петров',
      middleName: '',
      position: Position.SENIOR,
      dateOfBirth: '11/01/2001',
      active: true
    },
    {
      id: 10,
      firstName: 'Павел',
      lastName: 'Петров',
      middleName: '',
      position: Position.MIDDLE,
      dateOfBirth: '11/01/2001',
      active: true
    },
    {
      id: 15,
      firstName: 'Павел',
      lastName: 'Петров',
      middleName: '',
      position: Position.MIDDLE,
      dateOfBirth: '11/01/2001',
      active: true
    },
    {
      id: 16,
      firstName: 'Павел',
      lastName: 'Петров',
      middleName: '',
      position: Position.MIDDLE,
      dateOfBirth: '11/01/2001',
      active: true
    }
  ]

  constructor() { }

  getData(): Array<Programmer> {
    return this.programmers;
  }

  remove(id: number) {
    this.programmers = this.programmers.filter(programmer => programmer.id !== id);
  }

  add(programmer: Programmer) {
    this.programmers = [...this.programmers, programmer];
  }
}
```

> Удаляю... (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] table.service.ts

> Данные внутри компонента (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] table.component.ts:37

Comment: Кажется, что в методе `remove`, после удаления нужно заново получить данные, то есть добавить строку `this.dataSource.data = this.tableService.getData();`

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin А здесь не заключается дело в жизненных циклах компонента?

Comment: А changeDetection сейчас какой стоит Default или OnPush у компонента?

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin простите, не понимаю о чем Вы(. Обновил код в вопросе. Убрал в коде console.log'и

Comment: Возможно, проблема в двух провайдерах у сервиса. Удалите у сериса `provideIn: 'root'`, получается, что у вас два экземпляра сервиса, вы смотрите в одном данные, а компонент работает с другим экземпляром

Comment: Если получится, то в ответе распишу подробнее почему так происходит

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin Не получилось. Если необходимо - могу отправить ссылку на репозиторий с проектом по удобному Вам каналу связи

Comment: Можно на stackblitz сделать пример рабочий, чтобы можно было посмотреть, ссылку можно добавить в сам вопрос, ну и репозиторий туда можно добавить

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ganwsz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.ts

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134676/discussion-between-sergey-glazirin-and--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае, проблема была с тем, что данные не были обновлены, после того как изменился массив в сервисе.

```
remove(id: number): void {
    this.tableService.remove(id);
    // здесь нужно получать данные
    this.getData();
  }
```

Для того, чтобы изменения подтягивались реактивно, можно использовать rxjs, что позволит избавится от постоянных получений данных.

table.service.ts

```
// Injectable пустой, так как сервис у нас провайдится непосредственно в сам компонент.
@Injectable()
export class TableService {
  private programmers: Programmer[] = [
    ...
  ];

  // создаем экземпляр BehaviorSubject
  programmer$ = new BehaviorSubject<Programmer[] | null>(this.programmers);

  remove(id: number) {
    this.programmers = this.programmers.filter((programmer) => programmer.id !== id);
    // передаем новое значение в subject.
    this.programmer$.next(this.programmers);
  }

  add(programmer: Programmer) {
    this.programmers = [...this.programmers, programmer];
    this.programmer$.next(this.programmers);
  }
}
```

table.compnent.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.scss'],
  providers: [TableService],
})
export class TableComponent {

  dataSource$: BehaviorSubject<Programmer[] | null>;

  constructor(
    private bottomSheet: MatBottomSheet,
    private tableService: TableService
  ) {
    // создаем подписку на список программистов
    this.dataSource$ = this.tableService.programmer$;
  }

  add() {
    this.tableService.add(programmer);
  }

  remove(id: number): void {
    this.tableService.remove(id);
  }
}
```

table.compnent.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="dataSource$ | async; let dataSource">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
   ...
  </table>
</ng-container>
```

С помощью async-пайпа у нас нет необходимости создавать разные отписки на события, все будет автоматизировано. При каждом изменении в subject будет осуществляться перерисовка списка.